# Algebraic closure for torsion points on elliptic curves

Tags: elliptic-curves, torsion-groups

In my book about elliptic curves I've read about torsion points of an elliptic curve $E$ defined over $K$, for $n$ positive:

$E[n]=\{P\in E(\overline{K})\mid nP=\infty\}$

I've got two questions about it:

1. Why do we disregard negative numbers for $n$? The book hasn't defined $K$ to be a residue field or anything of the kind.
2. The book emphasizes that $P$ can be in the algebraic closure, but why exactly would they emphasize that? what goes wrong when we don't look at its closure?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where did you "disregard" negative numbers for $\;K\;$ ?? In fact, where did you even talk about negative/positive numbers at all in this context?

Comment: If you don't take the algebraic closure to define  $\;P\;$ it could be tyhis is the empty set, or many points are left out...

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant negative numbers for $n$. If I reread this it indeed makes no sense. As for the second comment, could you give me a small example?

Comment: When I think about it, if we define $n$ to be the order it would make sense to only include the positive values...

Comment: @Yongg : 1) $E[-n] = E[n]$ for any $n \in \Bbb Z$. 2) Notice that it is possible to look at torsion points over $K$, i.e. $E[n] \cap E(K)$. Usually we take the algebraic closure because we can look at the action of the absolute Galois group of $K$ on $E[n]$ (and its Galois cohomology).

Comment: @Watson Thank you. I was a little confused since I am going to work with finite fields either way and therefore all points on the curve should be torsion points. Could you then enlighten me on the algebraic closure of a finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$ for $p$ prime, or is that too dependent on the value for $p$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) We have $E[-n] = E[n]$ for any $n \in \Bbb Z$, so we may assume that $n \geq 0$.

2) Notice that it is possible to look at torsion points over $K$, i.e. $E[n] \cap E(K)$. 
But usually we take points with coordinates in the algebraic closure because we can look at the action of the absolute Galois group of $K$ on $E[n]$ (and its Galois cohomology).
Many properties work better when we look at the algebraic closure. Typically, the multiplication-by-$n$ map is surjective on $\bar K$-points, i.e.
$$[n] : E(\bar K) \to E(\bar K)$$
but it is *not* surjective on $K$-points, in general (this precisely gives rise to Galois cohomology groups). Compare with the fact that the $n$-th power map $\bar K^{\times} \to \bar K^{\times}$ is surjective, while the $n$-th power map $K^{\times} \to K^{\times}$ is not always surjective.

---

As for your further comment, the field $\Bbb F_p$ has a unique field extension of degree $n$ for any $n \geq 1$ ; we denote it by $\Bbb F_{p^n}$. Then we may write $\overline{\Bbb F_p}$ as the "union" (or "direct limit") of the fields $\Bbb F_{p^n}$.